# Accord Decision Tree null output on node

Tags: c#, .net, decision-tree, accord.net

I am using .net framework in my project and I run into the problem.

I am using 7 DecisionVariables to create a decision tree. 5 of them are Continuous, 2 of them are Discrete and I am using C45Learning.

Way I am creating Decision Varibale:

Continuous

```
new DecisionVariable(SupportedValueType.ToString(), DecisionVariableKind.Continuous)
```

Discrete (in my case i created Discrete variable representing Day of month)

```
int PossibleValues = 30; 
new DecisionVariable(SupportedValueType.ToString(), PossibleValues)
```

Now when I create a tree, its leaf nodes are nodes with Discrete decision variable and the output on this node is NULL, so when i run

```
tree.Decide(sample)
```

and it ends in this leaf node, it returns NULL.

**Can anybody tell me what the problem is ?**

---

When I was creating an input to create this Decision tree, I did not "use" every of this 30 possible values, only 2-3 of them. Could it be the problem ?

For example: (x variables are values of other decision variables and of course i provide more input data, not only 3 rows, but i only changed x values and only used this 3 days)

```
input:     label:

x,x,x,x,x,1 -> Small
x,x,x,x,x,2 -> Medium
x,x,x,x,x,3 -> Big
```

Comment: I see no problem mr.Problem :D

Comment: Do you mean that your training data did not contain all examples that could be seen in the test data? Then in this case indeed there will be a problem when running the tree. If you are still having the issue, could you post an example dataset and code snippet reproducing the issue to https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/689 ?

Comment: As of release 3.8.0, decision trees will default to a recursive decision method that will not throw exceptions when unknown variable values are found during the decision process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my guess is that your tree is simply incomplete.

When using that algorithm, if I do not provide it with a comprehensive training set containing every possible combination of the input columns, then my chance of getting null leaves is much higher.  However, this algorithm is known for having null paths anyway as a byproduct of its pruning process.

Check to see if other samples also return null.  If they all do, then you might have an issue.  If only a couple are returning NULL/unknown then it is probably simply a result of the way the tree built itself.  In that case you will need to handle it with a default decision value.

I have read that there are default values you can provide for the algorithm to apply on its own, however I have never used those.